# Перевод предлагаемой правки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Добрый день

в предлагаемой правке не все пункты переведены :

> ```
> Принять правки, которые однозначно улучшают сообщения
> Улучшить правку when you can make additional improvements to the post
> Отклонить и редактировать to replace an ineffective edit with your own substantive changes
> Отклонить edits that fail to improve the post or that make it worse
> Пропустить , если вы не уверены и хотите перейти к следующей предлагаемой правке
> ```

Comment: Спасибо, поправим.

Answer (score 2):

на всякий случай — ссылки на переводы:

[tx 7531](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/65381536) *edits that fail to improve the post or that make it worse*
**уже есть перевод (судя по всему, не совсем удачный):** *правки не улучшает сообщение или делают его хуже*

[tx 7532](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/65381537) *to replace an ineffective edit with your own substantive changes*

[tx 7533](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/65381538) *when you can make additional improvements to the post*

---

### предлагаемые переводы.

для контекста я привожу и начало фраз, а ту часть фраз, которая пока не переведена, выделяю жирным шрифтом:

tx 7531: Отклонить **исправления, которые не улучшают сообщение, или даже делают его хуже**

tx 7532: Отклонить и редактировать **для замены неподходящего исправления на вашу собственную версию**

tx 7533: Улучшить правку **, если знаете как сделать сообщение лучше**

---

в последнем случае, вероятно, лучше бы запятую добавить к переводу начала строки («Улучшить правку»). если, конечно, этот перевод не используется как самостоятельная фраза.

Comment: О, спасибо. Предложите варианты?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, предложил.